# Siri shortcuts voice input

Tags: iphone, siri

Is there a possibility to make voice input with Siri shortcuts? I haven't found it. What I want to do is to create a new todo item on my todo app in my case trello, but I don't want to manually type the todo item in, but dictate it via voice. Say "trello new card: [INPUT]" and then it creates the card. Is this possible? Also to send a message it would be nice to be able to have voice input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yay my first Shortcuts question!

Use the **Dictate Text** action.

[image]

This action will convert words you speak into to text and pass that text to the next action.

Currently, there is a bit of down side: You will not be able tell Siri in one sentence "Tell [Shortcut Trigger], Apples are cool" Instead you need to do it in two parts "[Shortcut Trigger]" wait... "Apples are cool".

**Warning**: Make sure to pick a language or it will silently fail.

Comment: Also, it seems to only work with plain text. I tried to say a number in order to then input it as a duration in the Health app but it doesn’t recognize it.

Comment: @bfontaine Does Siri recognize it?

Comment: @bfontaine I came across this too, but you can work around it by saying "five point oh" or "five point zero" and it's then recognised as a number instead of the word "five".

Comment: Thanks! Just used this to create a Wunderlist shortcut to add a new item to a shared list!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer regarding dictation: if you need to pass numbers, you can use Match (regex) combined with Get Numbers:

[image: get numbers from dictation apple shortcuts]

The reason you need Match is because if you use Get Numbers by itself, and you speak a phrase with words and a number in it (needing only the number), Get Numbers will not return the number. It will return Yes/No (True/False) indicating if there is a number in the input.

Therefore, you use Match to find the number itself in the passed input and pass THAT result to the Get Numbers function. Dictation will spell out the numbers one-nine, and use integers for 10+, hence the regex that I used. Here is the plain text for copy/paste:

```
(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|[\d]+)
```

You don't need either of the Show Results in your shortcut; I've included them so you can see the input as it moves through the shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

I passed through a calculation adding 0 to the text to convert from text to a number