# How do I create a Dictation Action on an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: siri

I'd like to set up a Siri command to add a Trello card to a specific board and I heard that the only way to do this is via Dictation?

Comment: I've seen this post, but I'm not sure where to start. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336799/siri-shortcuts-voice-input

Comment: Is this for iOS (iPhone/iPad) or for macOS?  Please update the question with what device and OS version you’re using.

Comment: Does anyone have ideas about how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. So, there is an application called Shortcuts.  Look it up.