# How do I get my iPhone to type the word "Period" instead of the punctuation while dictating?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-dictation

I love using my iPhone to dictate long emails, first drafts of documents, and such.  It does such an amazing job and I can capture my thoughts quickly.

Unfortunately, a lot of the work I do is associated with accounting periods but however I say "period", it always puts the full-stop punctuation.

Is there a way to get it to actually spell out "period"?  I end up having to use a word that will not be in the final text (penguin) and then do a search and replace at the end.

Comment: Try saying "literal period".

Comment: Doesn't work in my iPhone 6s, running iOS 12.1.

Comment: Use British English as dictation language?

Comment: True, that would work.  I figure there must be a way to do this without having to change the language... also, I don't necessarily want words such as "color" to be spelled "colour" and I _really_ don't want to have to say "full stop" instead of "period".

Comment: @KevinBuchan so you literally mean you want to use "period" as a full stop as well as the *word* "period"? I assume you expect the iPhone to recognize the context of what you want to dictate and this won't work. Siri is not an AI. It won't recognize what you *intend* when saying this or that. As long this fact doesn't change, you need to change e.g. your vocabulary using words like 'term' or 'interval' or eligible or you use british english for now...

Comment: I literally want to use the word "period" (as in "accounting period") and I need to use punctuation, of course.  
Siri can, in fact, use context to determine what you mean, but that's not what I'm asking for.

In the same way you can say "cap" to mean for the net word to be capitalized, I'm looking for something to mean "I don't mean the punctuation".  Nimesh had a great suggestion, but it just doesn't work.

Can you understand that?  (I didn't think it was that complex.)  Having to change a language to be able to dictate a word is just silly... might be a limitation of Siri, but silly.

Comment: @KevinBuchan I totally understood what you want to achieve. First of all, you are a bit wrong with Siri. Siri doesn't know what you intend you want it to do. It simply can't technically. It is only capable doing things that it already knows, it doesn't really learn - and if it does then it only learns in the limited capacities it does have for each purpose. **But** I think there is a way we could manage this via the shortcuts app. You may configure a routine, that replaces full stop with your word. Take a look at this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336799/siri-shortcuts-voice-input

Comment: Oh, I didn't say or mean to imply that Siri is learning.  All I meant to say is that Siri can use context (meaning the other words in the sentence) to better guess what I'm saying and what form of a homophone I mean to use.
You suggestion is very cool and I'm exicited to use it for some things, but it really isn't practical in this case because I cannot use a "shortcut" as part of a sentence, I have to say it by itself... that's even more cumbersome than using a single word I bulk-replace later.

Try it... say, "I got a new dog.  I knew that was the breed for me." Siri *gets* it.

Comment: @KevinBuchan As you may try to solve this issue with workarounds, please feel free to address this issue to Apple: https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html Sometimes they even care ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the perfect solution, and it goes as follows.

1. Create a new contact with the first name of what you want to be dictated, as you want it dictated exactly. (e.g. Contact first name "period" without the quotes.)
2. Down at the bottom select add new field and add the phonetic first name field.
3. Go back up and type out the phrase you'd like associated with the word. I like to use the word "literal" space then the word. (e.g. "literal period")
4. Force quit all apps. and reopen the one you are using to dictate to.
5. make a new sentence and say the phrase "literal period" and you should now get the word "period" in the sentence instead of "."

To conclude, this works for EVERYTHING. Proper Names, fantasy/sci-fi content, technical terminology, etc.

Comment: Wow.  It's unfortunate that the new Siri Shortcuts don't support this type of solution, but your suggestion works PERFECTLY.  I have tried it and I can't even trick it into messing up.  Thank you... see you later.

Answer (score 1):

You are so correct. Dictation around this is really bad and the algorithm seems highly skewed to always prefer punctuation.

- That movie was a very nice period piece.
- Even the period penguin trick is problematic. (although the idea of an accounting penguin makes me surprisingly happy)
- The periodic table of elements is often punctuated.

Reading any of these will get you lots of dots. Anecdotally, I feel my iPad Pro (the new one with the A12X) and the iPhoneX and newer have better dictation than any Mac or older iOS device, but reading the three sentences above - several times, slowly, in a low noise environment makes me think most people aren't going to be getting the word period when they want it while dictating in 2019.